# Slick carousel is broken and some portion of next slide is shown on each slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slick slider on my website, but I have some issues with it. It looks completely broken (it's not showing the full content that I wanted to show) and the some portion of next slide is shown in each slide, I've made a code snipped, but the code was too big. I also added a picture of the same. So please guys help me out!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.slider').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayspeed: 3000,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  arrows: true,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
  </script>
```

```css
.main-banner {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 226px 0px 120px 0px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-banner:after {
  content: '';
  background-image: url(../images/slider-left-dec.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 60px;
  width: 262px;
  height: 625px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.main-banner:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url(../images/slider-right-dec.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 60px;
  width: 1159px;
  height: 797px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.main-banner .left-content {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.main-banner .left-content h6 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #4da6e7;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-banner .left-content h2 {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #2a2a2a;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.main-banner .left-content p {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 45px;
}

.main-banner .right-image {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}

.main-banner .right-image img {
  max-width: 593px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-banner wow fadeIn" id="top" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row slider">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 align-self-center">
              <div class="left-content show-up header-text wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1s">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h6>Graphics Designing</h6>
                    <h2>Designs to make you stand out.</h2>
                    <p>We don’t want you to ride a design trend that fades into obscurity and we don’t want you to become irrelevant by never adapting; we aim to place you in a position where your designs will be current, relevant, and suit both you and your customers.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="border-first-button scroll-to-section">
                      <a href="#contact">Get In Touch</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="right-image wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                <img src="assets/images/slider-dec-v3.png" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 align-self-center">
              <div class="left-content show-up header-text wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1s">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h6>Web Development</h6>
                    <h2>Online presence of your Business.</h2>
                    <p>Using the best-in-class technology, We build websites and apps that perform well and works exactly as per your requirements. It’s all about balancing the codes and creativity to offer eminent products.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="border-first-button scroll-to-section">
                      <a href="#contact">Get In Touch</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="right-image wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                <img src="assets/images/slider-dec-v3.png" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 align-self-center">
              <div class="left-content show-up header-text wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1s">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h6>Game Development</h6>
                    <h2>Creating the world of refreshment.</h2>
                    <p>Embracing game development on most popular platforms and reaching the attention of players with a wide variety of preferences is one of our main features. Expertise of our team allows us to cover all gaming platforms and develop an amazing product that matches the customer’s vision and players preferences.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="border-first-button scroll-to-section">
                      <a href="#contact">Get In Touch</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="right-image wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                <img src="assets/images/slider-dec-v3.png" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 align-self-center">
              <div class="left-content show-up header-text wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1s">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h6>App Development</h6>
                    <h2>Designs to make you stand out.</h2>
                    <p>Using solid expertise in mobile apps development, our team will help you create practical and seamless experiences on any device and get the best of mobile technology for your business. With so many ways to build mobile apps, we have expertise in choosing what the best solution is for your mobile app development strategy</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="border-first-button scroll-to-section">
                      <a href="#contact">Get In Touch</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="right-image wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                <img src="assets/images/slider-dec-v3.png" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

[this is how it's look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHZlV.jpg)

Comment: Hi! could you please share link because the slider is working fine

Comment: Add JQuery and Slick js and it should work https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js

Comment: @JaswinderKaur Thank you so much mam for your concern, but I didn't host this site yet and that why how can I share you the link, and yup you are right, the slider looks working but the some of the portion of the next slide is shown on each slide could you help me for that!

Comment: Ok.. in that case, please check the top div/sections style or slick tracker style in some cases when we set margin padding to slick elements it starts cutting edges

Comment: @Lasha Thank you so much for your concern, but dude it's still not working

Comment: one more thing, every time you remove margin/padding (Inspection window) just move the slide and check again

Comment: @JaswinderKaur Thank you so much mam, Now its Perfectly working, once again thank you so much